# upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04lts to Lubuntu 13.10

Tags: lubuntu

I want to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04lts to Lubuntu 14.04lts----but understand that the preferred method is to advance one step at a time so lubuntu 13.10 would be the best option--- however my concern is unity desktop  since I understand it is not fully supported in Lubuntu----

Please advise    Vince.F

Comment: You can, and *should*, upgrade directly to 14.04. There is no benefit to upgrading step-by-step, unless you want see what changes each release brings. 13.10 or 14.04, changing Ubuntu to Lubuntu is a task independent of upgrades, and a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

muru's comments are spot on.  Since you already have Ubuntu 12.04 which is a LTS version, upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 which is a LTS version.  That is the easiest way.  Once that is accomplished you can change your distro to Lubuntu by adding LXDE which will make it Lubuntu.  You will still have all of the Ubuntu applications and the Lubuntu applications.  For instance LibreOffice Writer and Abiword.  You can uninstall all of the Ubuntu applications or just leave them installed.  There is no direct method to go directly from Ubuntu 12.04 to Lubuntu 14.04.  The only Lubuntu releases that have not reached their End Of Life are; 14.04 (LTS), 14.10, and the newly released 15.04.  You have one other option and that is to back up your data to an external source, which should be done anyway, and to do a fresh install.